# Что хранит BITMAPINFOHEADER.biSizeImage?

Tags: winapi, изображения, структуры-данных, gdi, bmp

Смотрел на [сайте](https://jenyay.net/Programming/Bmp) описание формата *BMP*, дошёл до поля  `biSizeImage`.

На сайте написано:

> `biSizeImage` обозначает размер картинки в байтах. Если изображение несжато (то есть предыдущее поле установлено в *BI_RGB*), то здесь должен быть записан ноль.

Но в самом изображении там записан не 0:

[image: размер изображения]

Там записан размер самой картинки (без заголовков), и он равен `w * h * 3` байт. Для примера я взял картинку 100x100 пикселей и получил 30 000 байт (байты переставлены местами, поэтому `00 00 75 30`16cc = `30 000`10cc)

---

И отсюда вопрос - что там всё таки должно быть записано?

P.S для примера взял картинку *BMP* с глубиной цвета 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда смотрите перевод документации по структурам WinAPI, сверяйтесь с сайтом Microsoft: [BITMAPINFOHEADER structure (wingdi.h)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader)

> biSizeImage - Specifies the size, in bytes, of the image. This can be set to 0 for uncompressed RGB bitmaps.

"Can be set to 0" - значит может быть установлен в 0, но не обязательно будет установлен.